# "You cannot auto-download or download past purchases with a different Apple ID for 90 days" when switching iTunes library from old PC to new PC

Tags: itunes, apple-id

I have migrated all of my music from my old laptop to my new desktop via iTunes Home Sharing. I can see all of it, but it will not allow me to play any of the music. It says:

> This computer is already associated with an Apple ID. You cannot auto-download or download past purchases with a different Apple ID for 90 days.

What does that even mean? When I go into "My Account" it says that 4 computers are authorized, but under manage devices there is only 1 computer listed and it was associated dec. 25, 2013, well past the 90 day rule. I'd like to get rid of my old laptop, which is why I'm trying to move all my music. Does anyone know what I should do?

Comment: read this http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4627

Comment: Did you actually use a different (new) Apple ID?

Comment: I did change my iTunes password. The Apple ID is the same though. What I don't understand is why it's telling me to wait 90 days when the last time the device was associated with a computer was Dec. 25, 2013. <sigh> I don't know if there's any answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have been just caught up in a mess with Apple Servers.

Presently there is a stampede going on at Apple Store, with people wanting to preorder the iPone6.

Reportedly the server was overloaded and had to be taken down, and has not been operating correctly since.

Others have reported similar problems.

Just hang in there till the dust settles, and keep trying.